# RHEL7 "Too many authentication failures for", MaxAuthTries has no effect

Tags: ssh, rhel, putty

I'm using Kitty (putty clone) and Keepass agent (similar to pagent). Keepass agent contains 5 ssh keys.

This setup works fine with all linux boxes I've encountered so far, 
connection to our new RHEL7 linux box fails with

type 2 (protocol error):
"Too many authentication failures for ..."

I added

```
MaxAuthTries 6
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and did a

```
systemctl restart sshd.service
```

but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in Kitty in revealed that after the 5 ssh keys 
an extra GSSAPI authentication attempt was made

```
Event Log: Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Event Log: Attempting GSSAPI authentication
```

this caused the 6th attempt too fail.

Setting

```
MaxAuthTries 10
```

solved this.

As Jakuje pointed out increasing MaxAuthTries is not the best approach so I reverted that change and went back to the Kitty config to disable
the unused  GSSAPI authentication .

```
Connection -> ssh -> auth -> GSSAPI : uncheck "Attempt GSSAPI authentication"
```

This solved the issue without lowering the security

Comment: rather turn off the failing authentication methods than bumping the amount. This is not much future proof nor secure.

Comment: It's worth knowing that public keys can be shared between multiple servers without any real security implications.  Some websites will tell you to generate new key pairs per server but there's really no reason to do so.  It's better to have one key per client machine (never copying that to another machine) than one key per server.

Comment: @PhilipCouling using the same key on multiple servers is a Security Threat, in that it increases your blast radius. if your one key is stolen is the attacker has access to every server that key protects

Comment: @PrestonDocks that's quite subjective since if an attacker can get one file off your machine that you personally never copy then they can almost certainly get 50.

Comment: @PrestonDocks docks if you are genuinely concerned about the risk of  a private key escaping then you can use a hardware key such as a YubiKey that's also pass encoded. In that context using a single key is likely more secure than 50 files on disk.